# curl command return 404 when using os/exec

Tags: go, curl, gitlab, gitlab-api

I try to get file from private `gitlab` repository using `os/exec` with `curl` and get `404` response status:

```
func Test_curl(t *testing.T) {
    cmd := exec.Command(
        `curl`,
        `-H`, `PRIVATE-TOKEN:token`,
        `https://gitlab.some.com/api/v4/projects/23/repository/files/.gitignore/raw\?ref\=master`,
    )
    t.Log(cmd.String())

    var out bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &out

    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    t.Log(out.String())
}
```

```
=== RUN   Test_curl
    t_test.go:166: /usr/bin/curl -H PRIVATE-TOKEN:token https://gitlab.some.com/api/v4/projects/23/repository/files/.gitignore/raw\?ref\=master
    t_test.go:175: {"error":"404 Not Found"}
--- PASS: Test_curl (0.25s)
```

but when I try to use the same command from `zsh`, I get right response:

```
% /usr/bin/curl -H PRIVATE-TOKEN:token https://gitlab.some.com/api/v4/projects/23/repository/files/.gitignore/raw\?ref\=master
```

```
.DS_Store
.vs/
.vscode/
.idea/
```

I think the problem in the `url`, but don't understand how to fix one.

Comment: Why would you execute curl from a Go program when the Go standard library is perfectly capable of fetching any url as well as curl?

Comment: @Erwin Bolwidt - In my pet project I want to add functionality to use commands from configuration file)))  (https://github.com/kozmod/progen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?` and `=` must not be quoted:

```
cmd := exec.Command(
    `curl`,
    `-H`, `PRIVATE-TOKEN:token`,
    `https://gitlab.some.com/api/v4/projects/23/repository/files/.gitignore/raw?ref=master`,
)
```

`exec.Command` does not spawn a shell, therefore shell globs do not need escaping.